# Proofing continuity statement using $\delta - \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

**My proof:
Let $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(p) - \epsilon > 0$. Since function $f$ is continuous then there exist $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - p| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(p)| < \epsilon$ $\implies f(p) - \epsilon < f(x) < f(p) + \epsilon$. Therefore, by the following inequality we showed that $0 < f(p) - \epsilon < f(x)$. Hence, $f(x) > 0$.**

However, how do you show the statement including $0$?

Comment: You have typed $\delta <0$ instead of $\delta >0$ at two places.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true for $f(p) \geq 0$. Consider $f(x)=-|x|$ and $p=0$. No $\delta$ can work in this example.